# Method never execute because of yield break statement, how to recover from it?

Tags: c#

I have to read multiple xml files from specific folder and store in list, but whenever I used `yield break; keyword`, the method wasn't called. I am totally stuck here.

Below is my code:

```
private IEnumerable<SyncEntity> GetUpdatedItemsOfTypePagination(string folderPath)
{
    int currentPage = 1;
    string finishFilePath = Path.Combine(folderPath, "GetUpdateItemsOfType_Finish.xml");
    while (true)
    {
        string xmlFileFullPath = Path.Combine(folderPath, $"GetUpdateItemsOfType{currentPage}.xml");
        bool pageReadCompleted = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) //wait max time of 1,000*0.1 = 100 seconds
        {
            if (!File.Exists(xmlFileFullPath))
            {
                if (File.Exists(finishFilePath))
                {
                    yield break;
                }
                Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1));
                continue;
            }

            List<SyncEntity> pageItems = GetUpdatedItemsPage(xmlFileFullPath);
            pageReadCompleted = true;
            foreach (var syncEntity in pageItems)
            {
                yield return syncEntity;
            }
            break;
        }

        if (!pageReadCompleted)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("Timeout reached for GetUpdatedItems method...");
        }

        currentPage++;
    }
}
```

Comment: This an iterator method. It won‘t be executed when you make the call in your code. The compiler injects code to create an enumerator class. The code is executed progressively during the iteration. I recommend you inform yourself about this concept before you use it in production code.

Comment: I've just woken up and my brains a bit fuzzy so forgive me I've not got what you're trying to do. Yield break will return from the whole method. Could you comment your code example and explain exactly what each bit is meant to be doing? And all these file variables are?

Comment: hello Dave, I am trying to search a folder for multiple files , and after xml files got then I am deserilizing that files and store in single list

Comment: This method won't be called until you start enumerating results (with foreach, ToList() and so on).